# Glossário Python, biblioteca é sinônimo de pacote? Modulo é sinônimo de classe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou estudando Python com vídeo aulas, e os professores usam muitos sinônimos que parecem a mesma coisa pra mim.

No caso desses dois termos são a mesma coisa? Módulo pelo que achei aqui mesmo seriam qualquer arquivo.py, mesmo o pacote é um arquivo.py, ou seja um modulo é uma classe?

Desculpem se estiver fazendo uma pergunta idiota.

Answer (score 3):

Nem sempre em todo lugar se usa essa terminologia da forma mais estrita - embora elas tenham um significado em comum, há diferenças:

**Classe** (class) - é o termo mais distinto dos outros: classe é uma única classe em Python, que em geral é definida dentro de um  arquivo de código Python, com o comando `class` (mas também pode ser criada em código C, ou criada dinamicamente, sem ter um comando `class` e um bloco correspondente). O importante é que ao contrário de outras linguagens, não há nenhuma limitação de quantas classes podem ser criadas em um  arquivo, nem nenhuma correspondência obrigatória entre o nome do arquivo e o nome de qualquer classe dentro dele. Em geral se recomenda, por questão de estilo e convenção, que os nomes das classes sejam em CamelCase (mas isso não é obrigatório).

**módulo** - esse sim, falando estritamente é o nome dado a tudo que é definido em um único arquivo ".py"

**pacote** - Nome dado a um diretório (ou outro conjunto, como um arquivo zip) contendo vários arquivos .py. Em geral uma pasta vai conter pelo menos um arquivo `__init__.py` (mesmo que vazio, com zero bytes) para ser considerada um pacote.

**biblioteca** (library) - esse nome tem uma definição um pouco menos precisa - pode designar um **projeto** externo, contido num único módulo, ou num pacote, 
 ou mesmo num conjunto de pacotes. As "bibliotecas" são projetos de terceiros, que não fazem parte diretamente da linguagem, e que são instaladas copiando os arquivos necessários para pastas específicas do sistema. Essa instalação em geral é feita automaticamente por ferramentas como `pip`, `conda` ou um instalador próprio . Mas não é incorreto chamar também de "biblioteca" um módulo ou pacote específico dentro da "biblioteca padrão". Exemplos de bibliotecas: requests, numpy, pandas, pillow.

**biblioteca padrão** ("standard library", frequentemente abreviada para `stdlib`): conjunto de pacotes e módulos que acompanham uma instalação padrão de Python, e são considerados como "parte da linguagem" - exemplos: `math`, `http.server`, `pickle`. Não é necessário instalar nada além do Python para ter as funcionalidades da biblioteca padrão, que podem ser importadas sempre que necessário.

Quando você está usando uma biblioteca, não tem importância se ela foi definida como um único módulo ou num pacote com vários arquivos. Mas é importante saber distinguir se você importou um módulo de dentro de um pacote, ou se importou uma classe. Em geral a dica está nos nomes - senão, você só pode contar com a documentação.

Por exemplo: `from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor` importa uma classe. Mas nem sempre a questão das maiúsculas é uma regra, e as vezes não tem importância saber. Por exemplo: em `from datetime import datetime` - o primeiro datetime pode estar definido num único arquivo, caso em que é um módulo, ou numa pasta com nome `datetime`, caso em que é um pacote - e isso na verdade não importa. Já o *segundo* `datetime` é uma **classe**, mas é menos usado para criar instâncias diretmente (com a chamada `datetime(ano, dia, mes, hora, minutos, segundos)`) do que para se chamar vários dos métodos de classe contidos dentro dela (quero dier: dentro da classe datetime) - por exemplo, os métodos `datetime.strptime`, `datetime.now`,  são todos métodos de classe que criam um novo objeto datetime, mas poderiam ser perfeitamente funções dentro de um módulo `datetime`: pra quem está usando, não faz diferença.